# How can I add a header/datamember to all DataContracts in a WCF service?

Tags: wcf

I am looking to extend existing services and add Authorization to every call being made. The problem I have is that I don't know how to do this in the best possible manner. What I need to do is to send the name of the module calling the WCF service. I already send the username and password for the service and now I need to extend that with the name of the module calling the service. This is because we might allow a user to open a module and display data from another module but not from a third.

If we would have used message contracts I would just add a MessageHeader for this and set that header when I create the request. That is unfortunately not an option with DataContracts so I was considering the following two alternatives.

Adding a DataMember in a base class with Order=1000 or something like that. I don't know what will happen if we add another DataMember before that though?

Create the property for the module name and set a header in the transport instead. Not really fond of this one though. It's pretty abstract and hard to follow.

Which one is the least evil or do you have a better suggestion?

**EDIT 1:** The problem is not how to send a header to the service the problem is how to send a header with a specific value to the server. In the message inspector I can only create generic instances with `message.GetBody<DataContract>();` this means I have to know the type which I don't know how to.

**EDIT 2:** The issue here is that in our application we want to restrict access to a call based on from where the call is made so I need to pass this information. Let's say I make the call to MyService from FindUserModule then I need to add the id of that module in a header so that the AuthorizationManager can check if that user really should be authorized. This is due to service calls being used from many modules.

Answer (score 1):

Handle this as SOAP header in [custom message inspector](http://weblogs.asp.net/paolopia/archive/2008/02/25/handling-custom-soap-headers-via-wcf-behaviors.aspx).

Comment: That would work with the data contract because it is used in the transport layer?

Comment: Also, would it be run before AuthorizationManager so that setting the IncommingMessageProperty would be useful?